# What does handle_redirect() in JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript

What will happen if I click a `<a href="javascript:handle_redirect();">XXX</a>`?

It seems I will be redirect to somewhere, but how does it determine where?

Comment: This is not a built-in function in Javascript, you will have to check the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your JavaScript code, you should have a function that looks like this :

```
function handle_redirect() {
   ...
}
```

To find your JavaScript code, look for script tags, like this ...

```
<!-- INLINE JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Inline JavaScript");
</script>
```

... or like this ...

```
<!-- an EXTERNAL external JavaScript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/myscripts.js"></script>
```

If your `handle_redirect` function is defined inline, you should be able to find it just by searching for `handle_redirect` in the code of your webpage.

Usually, however, your JavaScript will be found in external JavaScript files. In that case, you need to search in the code of files that are linked to. So, if you see a script tag with a `src` eg. equal to `assets/js/myscripts.js`, just open the file `assets/js/myscripts.js` with your text editor OR your browser and look for a function that looks like `function handle_redirect() { ... }` there.